# Platform-specific-css in Nativescript Angular

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm trying to apply **platform-specific-css** in my **Nativescript Angular** Mobile App.

For example, for the home component, currently I have `home.component.tns.css` to style it. But I also need to handle some styles separately for IOS and Android.

Here's what I have tried:

1. Add a css file named as `home.component.ios.tns.css`. Not working, the css in this file won't be applied.
2. Add a css file named as `home.component.ios.css`. This time the css is applied. But I lost the css in `home.component.tns.css`
3. I import `home.component.tns.css` in `home.component.ios.css` like this: `@import './home.component.tns.css';` This time I got an error saying *NativeScript encountered a fatal error: Error: Could not resolve home.component.tns.css*

I guess I wasn't using the platform specific css in the right way. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are doing a shared-project (web + NS in 1 project).

To set up platform specific styling in NativeScript you need to name your files like this:

`home.component.ios.css`

`home.component.android.css`

In your `home.component.ts` you'll set up your styles binding like this:

`styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']`

NativeScript will take the respective platform `.css` file and generate the contents of the base `home.component.css` file with the platform specific style sheet `.ios.css` or `.android.css`.

Comment: The Angular CLI automatically generated 5 files for my component, including: *XX.component.html, XX.component.css, XX.component.ts, XX.component.tns.html, and XX.component.tns.css*. I'm using the files with tns suffix to develop my nativescript project. Currently I do have imported `home.component.css` in `styleUrls`, and the styles in `...tns.css` will work(that's all good).  My problem is, if I create the file `home.component.ios.css`, only this file will work, and the `...tns.css` file will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You can't import `home.component.tns.css` because there will only by `home.component.css` available.

You can put all your css in `home.component.ios.css`.
Or you can use the `.android` and `.ios` classes like :

```
.ios .myClass {
    background-color: red;
}

.android .myClass {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make both *home.component.ios.css* & *home.component.tns.css* available? Cause I do need the `....tns.css` file to store some shared css code, and `....ios.css` / `....android.css` file to store platform specific css.

Answer (score 0):

The platform specific files should be like:

- yourcustom.component.css
- styles.component.ios.css
- styles.component.android.css